# How to Set Color in Crystal Report Draw Box And Data Bind. .?

Tags: crystal-reports

> How to Set Crystal Reports Draw box Inside fill color ?.
>
> How to Bind data with details data using dataset in crystal reports ?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace box with text object.

Insert text object and add border lines if necessary.  Then to add fill color, right click on the text object > Format Text > Go to Border tab > Check background and set color.